# Azure Data Factory - moving data from On-Premise SQL to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

A simple question: Can this be achieved directly? I mean without the Azure blob storage in between (as showed in all the examples)? Can someone provide some code example please.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do this directly. In fact, you can do direct copies from any of our supported sources/sinks, you don't have to pass through blob.  To go from on-prem SQL Server-->SQL azure, you will need to setup a Data Management Gateway connector on your on-prem server.  Then, you use a linked service of type AzureStorage and an output dataset of type AzureSQLTable as the output dataset, instead of AzureBlob as is shown in the example.  The exact steps to setup the DMG and the JSON code for the linked services, datasets, and pipelines can be found in our documentation.  We are also improving our UI in the near future to make these kinds of copy setups an easy code-free experience.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-sqlserver-connector/